# How to run Google Chrome in translate mode?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, translation

How to open a page with Chrome in translate mode from the command line? I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
"[...]\chrome.exe" http://exemple.ru -translate=ru-en
```

Comment: [Here](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches) are the list of currently supported command line arguments for chrome

Answer (score 0):

You could open an URL with Google Translate like:

```
...\chrome.exe http://www.google.com/translate_c?langpair=ru|en&u=http://exemple.ru/
```

or SU in Russian:

```
...\chrome.exe http://www.google.com/translate_c?langpair=en|ru&u=http://www.superuser.com/
```

Comment: thanks! But I don't want to translate my page with [Google translate website](http://translate.google.com/) but [Google Chrome translation tool](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=173424)